# Want allow only lower case or "_" using sfValidatorRegex in symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, design-patterns

I want to allow only lower case charecters or "_" character for text box using  sfValidatorRegex of Symfony 1.4.

I had used different types of patterns like `/^[a-z_]+$/i` but they didn't work for me.

So if anyone can know, please help me out.

Comment: This pattern should work. How do you use it in the form?

Comment: I am using like this :

$this->validatorSchema["access_key"] = new sfValidatorRegex(array('required' => true, 'pattern' => '/^[a-z_]+$/i'));

but it shows me always invalid message event i m entering lower case data like 'ssdffd'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Pattern is `'/^[a-z_]+$/'`

Comment: Hmm... Yes this is working now it should be '/^[a-z_]+$/' not '/^[a-z_]+$/i' :) Thanks Hardik